# How to import .java from another project AND package in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, import

We're working on a project (Project A) in college that has to extend from a class that is another project (Project B), made years ago.
This is working under Eclipse, and developing apps for android, so this is in fact Activities we're talking about.

So far I've tried this:

- Adding project B on Project A's build path (In the Projects TAB)
- Importing, with full package name and .java name.

The thing is that every solution I've found is for working with .jar, .class or even .apk files, but I'M NOT working with that, project B is a simple project full of .java files.

To be a little more clear about it, Project A has a class named ClassFromProjectA, and Project B has a class like `ClassFromProjectB`. `ClassFromProjectA` is like follows:

```
public class ClassFromProjectA extends ClassFromProjectB{}
```

ClassFromProjectB is like follows:

```
public class ClassFromProjectB extends ListActivity implements OnInitListener, OnGesturePerformedListener {}
```

The "only" thing ClassFromProjectB is doing is, uppon extending from it, it changes the default layout for a ListView, applies specific navigation options, applies gestures to every activity extending from it, and a couple more tweaks.

If I make this:

```
public class ClassFromProjectA extends ListActivity{}
```

Everything works fine with my class, no errors, no warnings, no nothing.

We are ABSOLUTELY sure that `ClassFromProjectB` is working, it was a previous succesfull college project, and it also has an Example activity within its files to check functionality, and everything works like a charm. That's the thing though, it only works because it is in the same project file. But we CAN'T do that, we have to import and extend, and it isn't workin'.

Please, let me know if you know how to make this work, or point me in the right direction.

Comment: what does "isn't working" mean? does it show some error when you compile?

Comment: Errors vary from "NoClassDefFoundError", "UnableToResolveSuperClass", "Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo" and a few others, all relating to not founding my class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you can do if you have the complete project B that you need to include inside your project (project A).

1. Make Project B a library in the following manner :

   - Right click the **project B** in Eclipse, and click on **Properties**.
   - Select **Android** then the **isLibrary** check box.
     [image: Project B Properties]
2. Once Project B is a library, you have to add the library B (formerly project B) in your project A in the following manner :

   - Right click the **project A** in Eclipse, and click on **Properties**.
   - Select **Android** then click on **Add...**.
     [image: Add Library]
   - You should see a list with all the library projects inside eclipse on your machine. You should also see **Project B**. Select it and click **OK**.
     [image: Library Selection]
   - You should see Project B in the list of libraries.
     [image: Project B added as Library]

Now you should be able to import packages from Project B to project A and use its classes with no problem.

Comment: Oh my..... you're ABSOLUTELY right. Yes, we found kind of a documentation *.pdf made by the students that developed the previous project. They were saying something about library, adding android:islibrary=true to Project B and android.library.reference.1=<something_too_long>, and now I realize that it is a relative path and not a package path, it should be rewriten (or linked by Eclipse, wich is by far easier). Thanks a lot!.

Comment: The problem now is that it keeps crashing, saying "Unable to Instantiate activity ComponentInfo" and it keeps saying "NullPointerException". I think this is an improvement, but I'm still not sure if it is working now (and then I have an error in my app) or it's not.

Comment: Is the activity **ComponentInfo** an activity that you created in Project A? Or an activity used in Project that is displayed ? In both cases you have to add the activity in the **AndroidManifest.xml** file of your project A , did you do that ?

Comment: No, it's not that. Is something the android emulator is throwing when attempting to launch my app. I've determined (debugging with logs everywhere :D) that ClassFromProjectB is entering its onCreate method, I'll further Log everything untill I know for sure where is app crashing.
PS: "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.alas.gravadora/com.alas.gravadora.Gravadora}: java.lang.NullPointerException"

Comment: Allright, I've found where the app is crashing. Right after invoking "super.onCreate()" on ClassFromProjectA, I invoke setContentView. Ok, one of the main things that Project B changes is precisely layouts, so maybe it is messing up with that, but no further error information is provided (it seems to be a NullPointerException around). If I make a Log entry right after the setContentView() it doesn't print in the Logcat. I thinks it's pretty safe to asume that it is messing everything up. I'll try no to do the setContentView and post back.

Comment: Allright, that's it! Thanks @Leeeeeelo for your answers, it turns out that layouts are all messed up and I have to fix it now.

Comment: It seems like you are setting a new layout that does not contain the needed layouts for it to work, that is possibly why you are getting a null pointer exception, that could triggered if a view retrieved by **findViewById** (returning NULL) is used. Happy Coding ! Please do not forget to choose the correct answer !

Answer (score 1):

Try reference projectB in projectA as follows:

1. Open "Properties" window of projectA
2. Go to "Android" Tab
3. Click "Add" button in the "Library"
4. Select projectB as reference

After this you can import class from projectB.

Comment: Yup, same answer as above. Thanks, that worked, but now facing another problem (or the same, not sure yet). See comment on the previous answer.