# Opportunity to using native methods systemwide. How to call method or how it should be named?

Tags: android-ndk, java-native-interface, android-build, native-methods

I want to use one native library for a plurality of applications. Library has compiled through android build system and now located in /system/lib/. It can be loaded in application through System.LoadLibrary("libexample"). But method in library which should be declared like

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_application1_MainActivity_method1
```

turning out unusable because library should be used by several applications. And of course this several applications have their own unique names. So I tried to named my method just like

```
 JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL method1
```

and call

```
public native String method1(String string);
```

But of course my application trying to find it as Java_application1_MainActivity_method1

How to call this method or how it should be named?

**Updated:**

I tried to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14257352/solved-how-to-import-java-from-another-project-and-package-in-android)(see post with green tick) tutorial to complete my project. I wrote
a library for using native method:

```
package com.example.mylib;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MyClass extends Activity {
public native static String MyMethod(String string);
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("nativeLibrary");
    }
}
```

Then I trying to use it in my application:

```
// Some no interesting inclusions
import com.example.mylib.MyClass;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
// Some no interesting code.
MyMethod(file.getAbsolutePath())
//Some no interesting code 
}
```

And it working as I need! But now I confused that my **import com.example.mylib.MyClass;**
"*never used*" in eclipse. And if I will create image with this "*Is Library*" project the latest will no resolving. Any idea?

Comment: 1. MyClass should not extend Activity, unless you really need this inheritance

Comment: 2. In MainActivity, you should call MyClass.MyMethod()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the same JNI signature in many applications. Your class may not belong to the default package of the application, as defined in AndroidManifest.xml. So what?

---

**Example:**

Start with HelloJni sample from NDK (in Eclipse, use Import -> Android -> existing Android Code, and point to the ${android-ndk-root}/samples/hello-jni).

Build it and run on device or emulator.

Open a new Android Application project, call it TestCrossJni.
The package name for our app will be: test.cross.jni - no relation to `com.example.hellojni`!

Choose "Create Activity" -> create Blank Activity.

Add new Java class to this project (`src/com/example/hellojni/HelloJni.java`):

```
package com.example.hellojni;

public class HelloJni
{
    public static String gets() {
        return stringFromJNI();
    }

    /* A native method that is implemented by the
     * 'hello-jni' native library, which is packaged
     * with this application.
     */
    private native String  stringFromJNI();

    /* this is used to load the 'hello-jni' library on application
     * startup. The library has already been unpacked into
     * /data/data/com.example.hellojni/lib/libhello-jni.so at
     * installation time by the package manager.
     */
    static {
        System.load("/data/data/com.example.hellojni/lib/libhello-jni.so");
    }
}
```

Edit `res/layout/activity_main.xml`: replace

line 12 `android:text="@string/hello_world" />`

with `android:id="@+id/hello_world" />`

In `src/test/cross/jni/MainActivity.java`, add the following after

line 12 `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

```
((android.widget.TextView)findViewById(R.id.hello_world)).setText(com.example.hellojni.HelloJni.gets());
```

Profit!

Comment: How to add a class in the AndroidManifest.xml and how it should be called in Main_activity?

Comment: No, only activities and  services must be declared in AndroidManifest.xml. Access to com.mp5package.mp5 from any Java class in your project is very similar to how it uses com.android.Activity class or com.java.nio.ByteBuffer

Comment: Sounds easy but how it look like in code? I never used ByteBuffer or so and not familiar with java.

Comment: Done. BTW, you can learn that you don't need to build a system image to use a shared native library.

Comment: Yes, this method works but it is not exactly what I need. Is it possible in java to use construction like **import com.some.thing** and then just use method like **method1()**? I know that does not necessary to build system image and using native method for counting md5 sum. It isn't my caprice but it is a part of my testwork and it should be done exactly how it should.

Comment: Using import, you write thing.method1()

Comment: Thanks for this info, this seems to be the only page on the entire internet that points out that the package name is irelevant.